# Counting words from a file in Python

Tags: python, count

I'm completely new to Python, but to my own surprise I've produced this working piece of code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
with open("wordlist.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line)    



with open ("cv000_29416.txt", "r") as myfile:
   data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
print (data.count("bad"))
```

The point is, that I want to count the words from wordlist.txt in cv000_29416.txt.

(So wordlist.txt contains for example twenty words like 'bad', 'good' etcetera, and cv000_29416.txt is a long text, and I want to count how many time 'bad', 'good' etcetera occure in cv000_29416.txt)

Can I insert that somewhere in the seconds piece of code?

Thank you!
and sorry for bad English

Answer (score 3):

```
# create a collection of the words that want to count
with open('wordlist.txt') as infile:
    counts = {}
    for line in infile:
        for word in line.split():
            counts[word] = 0

# increment the count of the words that you really care about
with open("cv000_29416.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for word in line.split():
            if word in counts:
                counts[word] += 1

for word,count in counts.items():
    print(word, "appeared", count, "times")
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: @HeleenFeijen: please consider marking an accepted answer, to indicate that the issue is closed

Answer (score 2):

use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) dict to count all the words:

```
from collections import Counter
with open ("cv000_29416.txt", "r") as myfile:
   data = Counter(myfile.read().split())
print (data["bad"])
```

To put it together, presuming each word is on a separate line in wordlist.txt:

```
from collections import Counter
with open ("cv000_29416.txt", "r") as myfile,open("wordlist.txt") as infile:
    data = Counter(myfile.read().split())
    for line in infile:
        print(data.get(line.rstrip(),0))
```

Comment: This potentially wastes space by keeping track of unwanted words. Ideally, you'd count ONLY the words in wordlist.txt

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, it would have to be  a pretty big file before it would make any difference, a counter dict is exactly the kind of thing the OP should be learning about as opposed to using  something like `print (data.count("bad"))`

Comment: Granted, `data.count("bad")` is bad (no pun intended). However, OP could maintain a dict with ONLY the required words, and manually increment the count as required. That would save on space, and be a lot more scalable (to large/sparse files). Also, since `collections` is written in python, it wouldn't be all that much faster than hand-written python code

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, yes the OP could do that but I am guessing the OP may want to do more than just count those words. Either way I would prefer to know about the Counter dict than not

Comment: OP states that they are interested in counting only the words from `wordlist.txt`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, my code does that so guess I answered the question asked then

Comment: Again, your code counts all the words in the big file, and prints only the required words. It doesn't not count the non-required words. So your statement `my code does that` is false

Comment: Interesting discussion. I learned about the Counter function, but somehow it doesn't work. I use Python 3.4.1, so that shouldn't be a problem. For now I'm very happy with the answer of inspectorG4dget